# jquery set and remove checked attribute doesn't work, javascript does

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

for clarity, let's say that I have a checkbox that I want to check and uncheck using two buttons.

I can check/uncheck the box using basic javascript, but with jquery, as soon as I remove the attribute, I cannot set it back... Any idea why?

I created a basic fiffle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/2K244/

```
<button id='button1'>check</button>
<button id='button2'>uncheck</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="myBox1" value="polo" />
<br/>
<button id='button3'>check</button>
<button id='button4'>uncheck</button>
<input type="checkbox" id="myBox2" value="polo" />
<br/>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $('#myBox1').attr('checked','checked');
    });
    $('#button2').click(function () {
        $('#myBox1').removeAttr('checked');
    });
    $('#button3').click(function () {
        document.getElementById('myBox2').checked = true;
    });
    $('#button4').click(function () {
        document.getElementById('myBox2').checked = false;
    });

});
```

Comment: it is a property not an attribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `.prop()` instead. From jQuery's documentation on [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) now.

http://jsfiddle.net/2K244/1/

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
    $('#myBox1').prop('checked',true);
});
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('#myBox1').prop('checked', false);
});
$('#button3').click(function () {
    $('#myBox2').prop('checked', true);
});
$('#button4').click(function () {
    $('#myBox2').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: that's not an answer to the question he asked.

Answer (score 0):

to uncheck a box, use the prop function. `$('#myBox1').prop('checked', false);` without quotes on `false`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why yours isn't working, but use this:

```
$("#myBox1").prop("checked",true);

$("#myBox1").prop("checked",false);
```

Make sure to have a recent version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The status of the checked state can be modified using the  `true` || `false` second parameter in the `.prop()` method.

```
$('#btn_checked').on('click', function() {
     $('#myBox1').prop('checked', true);
});

$('#btn_unchecked').on('click', function() {
     $('#myBox1').prop('checked', false);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2K244/6/)